# Python class object creation in inheritance

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following class in python:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.id=8
        self.value=self.get_value() #Mark-1
    def get_value(self):
        pass
    def should_destroy_earth(self):
        return self.id ==42

class Baz(Foo):
    def get_value(self,some_new_parameter):
        pass
```

Here, i can create an object of class *Foo* as such:

> ob1 = Foo() #  Success

However, if i try to create an object of *Baz*, it throws me an error:

> Ob2 = Baz() # Error

```
  File "classesPython.py", line 20, in <module>
    ob2 = Baz()
  File "classesPython.py", line 4, in __init__
    self.value=self.get_value()
TypeError: get_value() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

If i remove the "self.get_value" in 3rd line of class *Foo*, i can create an object of class *Baz*.

Isn't is the case that when we inherit a class in python, the ***init*** method of the superclass isn't inherited by the subclass and we need to explicitly call them (e.g. Superclass.**init**(self) )?

So when i create an object of Baz, the __init__method of the Foo() class isn't invoked by default. So why can i not create the object for Baz ?

Comment: Isn't the real problem here that `Baz` doesn't actually support the same interface as `Foo`, and therefore *shouldn't* be a subclass of it? Could you give a less abstract example?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but this is more towards understanding the idiomatic approach of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't is the case that when we inherit a class in python, the init
>   method of the superclass isn't inherited by the subclass and we need
>   to explicitly call them (e.g. Superclass.init(self) )?

No, this is only the case if the subclass has an `__init__` method.

Comment: I see, so i made a __init__ method in the subclass Baz and now i can create an object. So the concept here is, if i inherit superclass the __init__ method gets executed only if i don't define __init__ method for the derived class. Is my assertion correct?

Answer (score 2):

No, you have some fundamental misunderstanding there.  The `__init__` method of `Foo` certainly ***is*** inherited by `Baz`.

Python will assume you want the same implementation of `__init__` for the subclass, because you didn't implement anything else.  You'll have to explicitly define it yourself in `Baz`, if you don't want that behaviour.